# Re assigning value of formData to a variable is returning an empty object in the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using formData with axios in my react frontend app in order to accommodate the image field. Tho, the data that I sent to the backend Django rest app is empty.

**Frontend axios request**

```
const addPost = (userInput, redirectTo) => dispatch => {


   const input = [];
   
   input[0] = userInput[0];
   input[1] = userInput[1];

   const postInput = userInput[2];


    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("title", postInput.title);
    formData.append("excerpt", postInput.excerpt);
    formData.append("content", postInput.content);
    formData.append("status", postInput.status);
    formData.append("image", postInput.image);
    formData.append("created_by", postInput.created_by);
    formData.append("category", postInput.category);
    formData.append("slug", "");

    input[2] = formData;

    axios
    .post(POST_ADD_URL, input)
    .then(response => {
         dispatch({type: ADD_POST_SUCCESS})
           toast.success(
                  " added successfully!"
              )
         dispatch(getAllPost())
         dispatch(push(redirectTo))
    })
    .catch(error => {
         dispatch({type: ADD_POST_FAIL})
         errorFilter(error)
         dispatch(push(redirectTo))
    })
```

}

This is mainly because I assigned the value of "***formData*** to another variable "***input[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2ele.png) = formData;***

**Backend code**

```
    def create(self, request):

    # filter data
    data = request.data

    # filter user by email
    author = data[0]

    # filter category
    category = data[1]

    # filter post
    post = data[2]

    print("\npost data\n")
    print(post)
    print("\n\n")

    serializer = PostSerializer(data=post)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    # filter instances
    user_instance = get_object_or_404(User, email=author['email'])

    category_instance = get_object_or_404(Category, name=category['category'])

    serializer.save(category=category_instance, created_by=user_instance)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you console.log your formData beafore you send the post request and show us the output?

Comment: I have added console log for data after the assignment and before the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because axios converts the input array to json and sets the content-type of the request to application/json. Converting FormData to json will return an empty object. If you want to send FormData though a request use

```
 // append the userInputs in the formData
 axios.post(url, formData);
```

Comment: I agree. But, I can't send only the formData. I have additional information to include in the request, that's why I used array.

Comment: Didn't know that, very intresting. Will this cause problem if you use json to get data on  backend like nodejs/express for example?

Comment: I have edited the answer to not include the headers, the browser will set the headers for you, actually setting the header will return an error.

Comment: body parser library can't handle multipart form data, that why we use multer to upload files to the server. So if your endpoint is expecting a file use multer to parse the body and access file through req.file.

Comment: You can create an endpoint that can receive the file in a multipar/form-data request, or you can append the inputs in your formData object.

Comment: Can I use multer in ractjs ?

Comment: multer is an express middleware, In react you can append the values you want to send to the server to your formdata. formData.append("userInput", input)